# c# delete dynamically created objects

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to remove all dynamically created object [ in this case, labels and trackbars ]

```
foreach (Label Labels in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    if (Labels.Tag.ToString() != "non-disposal"){
        Labels.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I tried this, but i get an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
"

thank you,

SOLUTION:

```
foreach (Label label in Controls.OfType<Label>()){

if (label.Tag != null && label.Tag.ToString() == "dynamic")
    label.Dispose();
```

thanks to lazyberezovsky

Comment: Why not just give your dynamically-created objects some *specific* tag? Or add them to a collection somewhere when you create them?

Comment: Why does it remove all labels? Presumably you have "non-disposal" set as the `Tag` for those you wish to keep?

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried that before, i get an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @GrantThomas excuse me, my last few sentences were completely wrong. sorry

Comment: @user1859829: Well that suggests you were trying to do it on a null refernece, which suggests you had a mistake. We can't tell why though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to all dynamic controls some `Tag`, e.g. `"dynamic"`. Then dispose them this way:

```
foreach (Label label in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    if (label.Tag != null && label.Tag.ToString() == "dynamic")
        label.Dispose();    
}
```

Looks like some label do not have `Tag` assigned. That's why you've got an exception trying to call `ToString()` on `null`.

Comment: @user1859829 only for every dynamic label which you want to dispose

Comment: @lazyberezovsky yes sorry, was reading it to quick. this was exactly what i have been trying for 2 days. thank you very much!

Comment: @user1859829 btw you don't need to remove control from parent controls - this is done in `Control.Dispose` method. If parent is not null, then control is removed from it

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove them from the controls collection.

```
var toDelete = Controls.OfType<Label>()
              .Where(c => (c.Tag ?? "").ToString() != "non-disposal")
              .ToList(); //need a list or array to avoid changing the collection as we remove from it
foreach (var ctrl in toDelete)
{
    Controls.Remove(ctrl);
    ctrl.Dispose();
}
//if this is part of a long method, also clear the list right away
// so the garbage collector can see them
toDelete.Clear();
```

Comment: I still get the error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." any solution?

Comment: I think I see where the null reference was. It looks like you already have another work-around, but this should work now, too.