# Delete dynamically created controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I keep getting stuck on this part of my program.
whenver i call an `listbox.selectitemchange` event, i want the proper amount of trackbar and labels to be displayed.

now, it does not work properly.
Some of them get removed when the event is called, some of them don't.

```
foreach (Label label in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    if (label.Tag != null && label.Tag.ToString() == "dispose")
    {
        label.Dispose();
    }
}

foreach (TrackBar trackBar in Controls.OfType<TrackBar>())
{
    if (trackBar.Tag != null && trackBar.Tag.ToString() == "dispose")
    {
        trackBar.Dispose();
    }
}


    for (int i = 0; i < calc; i++)
    {
        //string[] LineWidthSplitted = lines[lineWidth].Split(' ');
        //Int32.TryParse(LineWidthSplitted[2], out WidthValue);


        Label Label = new Label();
        Label.Name = "TrackbarWidth" + LabelName++;
        Label.Tag = "dispose";
        Label.Text = "Board -" + LabelName + "- Height:";
        Label.Location = new Point(10, 450 + (50 * LabelName));
        Label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
        this.Controls.Add(Label);



        TrackBar trackBar = new TrackBar();
        trackBar.Name = "TrackbarWidth" + trackbarName++;
        trackBar.Tag = "dispose";
        trackBar.Maximum = 85;
        trackBar.Minimum = 65;
        trackBar.SmallChange = 5;
        trackBar.TickFrequency = 5;
        trackBar.Value = 65;
        trackBar.Location = new Point(150, 450 + (50 * trackbarName));
        trackBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
        this.Controls.Add(trackBar);


        lineWidth += 4;

    }
```

while, when i remove the foreach for the trackbar, all labels get properly displayed. 
they all get deleted, en recreated for the pricese amount needed to be created, no exceptions.

Any reason why?

thank you.

Comment: Well, if all Labels you create, have "dispose" as Tag, and all Labels with "dispose" as Tag are supposed to get disposed of, what is the problem?

Comment: because, when i call the foreach to get the trackbars to be removed. some of them still stay [trackbars AND labels]  and i can't find any reason why.

Comment: Try removing them from the parent.

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry, i am not that good in c#. how do you do that? can you help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# delete dynamically created objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193148/c-sharp-delete-dynamically-created-objects)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use "Dispose" on the labels right away. First remove them. Note that you can't modify the Controls collection inside the foreach so you have to do something like this:

```
List<Label> itemsToRemove = new List<Label>();
foreach (Label label in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    if (label.Tag != null && label.Tag.ToString() == "dispose")
    {
        itemsToRemove.Add(label);
    }
}

foreach (Label label in itemsToRemove)
{
    Controls.Remove(label);
    label.Dispose();
}
```

If you want to remove all different kinds of controls in one swoop:

```
List<Control> itemsToRemove = new List<Control>();
foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
{
    if (ctrl.Tag != null && ctrl.Tag.ToString() == "dispose")
    {
        itemsToRemove.Add(ctrl);
    }
}

foreach (Control ctrl in itemsToRemove)
{
    Controls.Remove(ctrl);
    ctrl.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, you'll have to do the same with the trackbar so you could just look for just "Control" types in Controls, check the tags, then remove all of them if you know that all the controls on your form with "dispose" in the tag need to be disposed at the same time. Makes sense?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. but yes, i need 3 types of controls to be removed. now i have just 3 of these codes you gave me as an solution. Are you saying there is an easier way?

Comment: Edited to show how you would remove all kinds of controls at once.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this now, but I think you should also remove the controls from the Form Controls collection where you have added them. By the way, in your case I think you could avoid the OfType extension and use the old fashioned for..loop that will allow to execute just one loop....

```
for(int x = this.Controls.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--))
{
    Control ctr = this.Controls[x]; 
    if (ctr Is Label && ctr.Tag != null && ctr.Tag.ToString() == "dispose")
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(ctr);
        ctr.Dispose();
    }
    if(ctr Is TrackBar && ctr.Tag != null && ctr.Tag.ToString() == "dispose")
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(ctr);
        ctr.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Notice how removing elements from a collection with a for..loop should be done in reverse order, from the end to start of the collection

Comment: The labels are now deleted properly. But the trackbars not. Some still stay when the event is called.